# How to get the same layout into different screens without changing any sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed a layout for normal screen size, so now if i want the same layout to support in different screens like tabs and so on without changing any size , how should i do it?

Comment: Please go through the following links [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) [Supporting Different Densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Answer (score 1):

Allways use layout_weight and design the layout with ratios not exact values so when you change the screen the ratio between the sizes will be same